# How to use if/else for image condition in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

In selenium webdriver i want to use if/else condition with java. Each steps need to be checked and need to execute one by one. For example

```
WebElement S = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'hash=A8901BC412112F73A9E06E7A8832F15C')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(S);
if (S!= null);
action.click().perform();
```

In this code, i need to check the Image once it present it need to perform the action else it need to skip the test case not to be failed.

Comment: @pburgr that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If element is not found `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` is thrown. So in the case `S` is `null` the code is not gonna run to the `if` condition. Better approach is:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By...));
```

combined with:

```
if (elements.size() > 0) {
   WebElement element = elements.get(0); 
   // do something with the element
}
```